# Visual Studio - VB.Net - Stack error thrown

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to learn more about programming language.
I am using the following code using Recursion.
I cause it to run until a stack exception is thrown.
Without traping the error and/or defensively coding to prevent
such a deep recursion: - Are there adjustments I can make
to free any stack space when this routine runs?

Module Module1
    Private var As Integer = 1

```
Sub Main()
    Take1(var)
End Sub

Public Function Take1(p1 As Integer) As Integer
    p1 = p1 + 1
    Console.Write(p1 & vbCrLf)
    Take1 = Nothing
    Call Take2(p1)
End Function

Public Function Take2(p1 As Integer) As Integer
    p1 = p1 + 1
    Console.Write(p1 & vbCrLf)
    Take2 = Nothing
    Call Take1(p1)
End Function
```

End Module

Comment: Um, no - you've got a pair of mutually recursive functions with *no stopping point*. How would you *expect* this to be salvaged without changing it to stop appropriately? (I'm not sure I'd call that "defensively coding" - it's more just "specifying a termination point".) How far would you *want* the code to keep recursing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is resulting in unbounded recursion. See link here that describes this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx

The link is saying that starting from .NET 2.0 you can't catch this type of exception with try-catch block and gives good reasons why not.